# In a pandas dataframe where the column names are datetime objects, how can I find the earliest instance of a True value for a given row?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a dataframe where the column ids are datetime objects, and the values are True or False

| id | 2023-10-30 00:00:00 | 2023-11-01 00:00:00 | 2023-11-03 00:00:00 | 2023-11-06 00:00:00 | 2023-11-08 00:00:00 | 2023-11-13 00:00:00 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Canada | False | False | False | False | False | true |
| France | False | False | False | False | true | true |
| Argentina | true | true | true | true | true | true |
| Australia | true | true | true | true | true | true |
| Morocco | true | true | true | true | true | true |
| Ethiopia | False | False | False | False | true | true |
| Nepal | true | true | true | true | true | true |

I want to add a new column that identifies when the earliest True value occurred for a given row. For example, Canada's first True entry occured on 11/13, while Australia's occurred on 10/30. The final output would look like this:

| id | 2023-10-30 00:00:00 | 2023-11-01 00:00:00 | 2023-11-03 00:00:00 | 2023-11-06 00:00:00 | 2023-11-08 00:00:00 | 2023-11-13 00:00:00 | Earliest True |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Canada | False | False | False | False | False | true | 2023-11-13 00:00:00 |
| France | False | False | False | False | true | true | 2023-11-08 00:00:00 |
| Argentina | true | true | true | true | true | true | 2023-10-30 00:00:00 |
| Australia | true | true | true | true | true | true | 2023-10-30 00:00:00 |
| Morocco | true | true | true | true | true | true | 2023-10-30 00:00:00 |
| Ethiopia | False | False | False | False | true | true | 2023-11-08 00:00:00 |
| Nepal | true | true | true | true | true | true | 2023-10-30 00:00:00 |

Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Comment: What have you tried, and where are you stuck? Like, just to start, do you know how to use `apply`? Is it actually relevant that the columns are datetimes or is that an unimportant detail? You can [edit] to clarify. For more tips, check out [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](/q/20109391/4518341)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [idxmax](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html):

```py
# convert the columns to datetime (if necessary):
# df.columns = [df.columns[0], *pd.to_datetime(df.columns[1:])]

df["Earliest True"] = df.iloc[:, 1:].idxmax(axis=1)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
          id  2023-10-30 00:00:00  2023-11-01 00:00:00  2023-11-03 00:00:00  2023-11-06 00:00:00  2023-11-08 00:00:00  2023-11-13 00:00:00 Earliest True
0     Canada                False                False                False                False                False                 True    2023-11-13
1     France                False                False                False                False                 True                 True    2023-11-08
2  Argentina                 True                 True                 True                 True                 True                 True    2023-10-30
3  Australia                 True                 True                 True                 True                 True                 True    2023-10-30
4    Morocco                 True                 True                 True                 True                 True                 True    2023-10-30
5   Ethiopia                False                False                False                False                 True                 True    2023-11-08
6      Nepal                 True                 True                 True                 True                 True                 True    2023-10-30
```